# Zend - dynamic pages

Tags: php, html, ajax, zend-framework

I have a video as background so I want only the content of the page to load since everything else is the same. I tried using Ajax, but I couldn't get it to work. Is there a way to achieve that ? 
Layout code:

```
/...
<body>
<video autoplay loop poster="/img/bg-still.png" preload="auto" id="bg">
    <source src="/img/bg.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>
<div id="wrapper">
    <header>
        <div class="top_line">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <?php
                    if ($user = $this->identity()) {
                        ?>
                        <div class="col-lg-6 pull-left">
                            <p>
                                <span class="welcome-show">Здравей, <?php echo $this->EscapeHtml($user->nick) ?></span>
                                <span class="rank">Ранк:
                                     <?php
                                     switch ($user->role) {
                                         case 1:
                                             ?> <span class="rank-vip">VIP</span> <?php
                                             break;
                                         case 2:
                                             ?> <span class="rank-vipplus">VIP+</span> <?php
                                             break;
                                         default:
                                             ?> <span class="rank-none">Никакъв</span> <?php
                                             break;
                                     }
                                     ?>
                                </span>
                                <span class="credits-show">Кредити: <?php echo $this->EscapeHtml($user->credits) ?></span>
                                <a href="/charge-credits" class="credits-charge-link"><img src="/img/ui-icon-credits" class="ui-icon-credits"/>Заредете кредити</a>
                                <a href="/edit" class="register"><span
                                        class="icon icon-settings ui-icon ui-icon-gear"></span>Настройки</a>
                                <a href="/logout" class="register"><span
                                        class="icon icon-logout ui-icon ui-icon-close"></span>Излез</a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    <?php
                    } else {
                        ?>
                        <div class="col-lg-6 pull-left">
                            <p>
                                <a href="/login" class="login"><span class="icon icon-login ui-icon ui-icon-key"></span>Влез</a>
                                <a href="/register" class="register"><span
                                        class="icon icon-register ui-icon ui-icon-person"></span>Регистрирай се</a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    <?php
                    }
                    ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div class="page_head">
        <div class="nav-container" style="height: auto;">
            <nav>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-3 pull-left">
                            <a href="/">
                                <div class="logo"></div>
                            </a>

                            <div class="beta">BETA</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-9 pull-right">
                            <div class="menu">
                                <div id="dl-menu" class="dl-menuwrapper">
                                    <button class="dl-trigger">Open Menu</button>
                                    <?php
                                    echo $this->navigation('navigation')->menu();
                                    ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content" id="content">
        <?php echo $this->content; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
/...
```

Comment: What does your JS code look like? Do you have jQuery on the page?

Comment: What's does your JS code look like?